# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll error while installing Cmder

Tags: cmder

Getting a missing api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll error while installing Cmder a console for Windows 7. My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to download Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145

I installed all Windows updates and restarted and finally got Cmder working. To start Cmder open the unzipped folder and go to the lambda icon and double click it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this some small things like

(1)first, clear all temp file
(2)install C++ Redistributable 2015
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145

(3)Update Your Windows (**most important**)

I Hope It Will Solve Your Issue.